# Looking for simple, web based task management tool with progress bar like in github

Tags: task-management

I want a really simple task management tool with only 3 columns: 
TODO, IN PROGRESS, DONE like the one provided in github projects.

Everytime I drag and drop a card from IN PROGRESS to DONE I need that satisfying progress bar increase..

Unfortunately github's task manager is not very comfortable: I need to open github --> select my repo --> click on Projects -> Click on the specific Project and only then I can see all my tasks. 
That's way too many clicks for my taste..

is there an alternative you would recommend?

BTW: I dont like trello. I know it's somehow possible to get a total progress bar there but it requires a lot of tweaking and using chrome.